# Append to string variable

Tags: javascript, string, variables, append

How can I append a word to an already populated string variable with spaces?

Answer (score 346, accepted):

Like this:

```
var str = 'blah blah blah';
str += ' blah';

str += ' ' + 'and some more blah';
```

Answer (score 26):

```
var str1 = 'abc';
var str2 = str1+' def'; // str2 is now 'abc def'
```

Comment: it's more of a onclick append to variable. can it be done with a single variable?

Comment: Sure thing. See my other answer below.

Comment: @Ronal - if there are any extra bits to your question, you should add them to the question rather than asking within the comments, including any information that might help you get a decent answer.

Answer (score 8):

```
var str1 = "add";
str1 = str1 + " ";
```

Hope that helps,

Dan

Answer (score 5):

Ronal, to answer your question in the comment in my answer above:

```
function wasClicked(str)
{
  return str+' def';
}
```