# How to add margin on targeted letter javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this in html

```
<div id="content">
  <h1 class="entry-title">"Homepage SlideShow"</h1>
</div>
```

I also have this in js

```
var content = document.getElementById("content");

var entryTitle = content.getElementsByClassName('entry-title')[0];
      var str = entryTitle.innerHTML;
      var newTitle = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str[i] == 'e') {
           newTitle += str.charAt(i).fontcolor("red");
        }
        else {
            newTitle += str[i];
        }
    }
    entryTitle.innerHTML = newTitle;
```

I added a color on the targeted letter but I don't have an idea how to add a margin. I want to add margin on the targeted letter like **margin = -20px**;. I'm new to javascript and I'm hoping someone could help. Thanks

Here's my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8tkbqcjo/10/)

Edit:

I have this font that doesn't look good on letter spacing. I don't want to use a span class in my html since I don't want to do it manually on every single page or post that I make.

For example: I want to move all i's to the left since it has the same spacing in any word.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/rvchwn6a/ using `margin:-20px;` seems a little extreme as it will mess up the letter but I have it doing what you asked for.

Comment: Are you trying to set *style* to the `nth` word? If so, maybe you could check this article https://css-tricks.com/a-call-for-nth-everything/ TL;DR: `::nth-word` to style the nth word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append with some `span` element.Then apply the style for that span element using inline `style` or `class` name with css

```js
var entryTitle = document.getElementsByClassName('entry-title')[0];
var str = entryTitle.innerHTML;
var newTitle = "";
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str[i] == 'e') {
    newTitle += '<span class="add">' + str[i] + '</span>'
  } else {
    newTitle += str[i];
  }
}
entryTitle.innerHTML = newTitle;
```

```css
.add{
/*add your style here*/
color:red;
margin:-20px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="entry-title">"Homepage SlideShow"</h1>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer! do you have any documentation for that '<span class="add">' + str[i] + '</span>'?

Comment: Its same  as html  element creator and `+` used for concatenate  the string and variable    .refer this thread [`append with string and varibale`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288095/append-to-string-variable) and [span](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjhn4WzoJXUAhXGK48KHRt3CX8QFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Ftags%2Ftag_span.asp&usg=AFQjCNH7spvEYDZS2_kefeKwAAYf2EpXIA&sig2=RoWXHKtCJfRuXR-NsRPl6A)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var content = document.getElementById("content");

var entryTitle = content.getElementsByClassName('entry-title')[0];
var str = entryTitle.innerHTML;
var newTitle = "";
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str[i] == 'e') {
    newTitle += "<span style='margin: 20px;'>" + str.charAt(i).fontcolor("red") + "</span>";
  } else {
    newTitle += str[i];
  }
}
entryTitle.innerHTML = newTitle;
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h1 class="entry-title">"Homepage SlideShow"</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with the CSS property `letter-spacing` apply on a `<span>` markup.

Here my jsfiddle bro --> http://jsfiddle.net/f6zn0svk/

`.letter-spacing { letter-spacing: 10px; }`

```
<h1 class="entry-title">"Hom<span class="letter-spacing">ep</span>age SlideShow"</h1>
```

Comment: This isn't a very good solution since the javascript in your solution doesn't work and even after correcting the selector your changes to the HTML cause new issues.

Comment: Yeah totaly agree but I dont know if the author really need a Javascript Solution. Actually this answer is the good one https://stackoverflow.com/a/44243143/5711528.