# How to append multiple child div nodes

Tags: javascript, append

I'm using this code i got from codepen to append div nodes to parent div and its working fine.

```
var el = document.getElementById('items'),

elChild = document.createElement("div");

elChild.innerHTML = '<div class="product"><a href="product1.html"><img  src="images/product1.png" alt="product1" /></a></div>'

el.appendChild(elChild);
```

How can i add more div elements to because i tried adding them as in the code below and it failed, Thanks in advance

```
var el = document.getElementById('items'),

elChild = document.createElement("div");

elChild.innerHTML = '<div class="product"><a href="product1.html"><img   src="images/product1.png" alt="product1" /></a></div>'
                    '<div class="product"><a href="product2.html"><img src="images/product2.png" alt="product2" /></a></div>'
                    '<div class="product"><a href="product3.html"><img src="images/product3.png" alt="product3" /></a></div>'


el.appendChild(elChild);
```

Comment: Concatenate the strings using `+`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append to string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288095/append-to-string-variable)

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a simple syntax error:

```
elChild.innerHTML = '<div class="product"><a href="product1.html"><img  src="images/product1.png" alt="product1" /></a></div> <div class="product"><a href="product2.html"><img src="images/product2.png" alt="product2" /></a></div><div class="product"><a href="product3.html"><img src="images/product3.png" alt="product3" /></a></div>'
```

Inner html takes in one entire string of text, not 3 separate strings as you posted.

Also it might be even better if you dynamically created the divs in your innerHTML since they follow a clear pattern:

```
var nProducts = 3, out="";
for(var i=1; i<=nProducts; i++){
    out+= '<div class="product"><a href="product'+i+'.html"><img src="images/product'+i+'.png" alt="product'+i+' " /></a></div>';
}
elChild.innerHTML = out;
```

This code should create the structure for `n` products in the div that you want.

*Edit according to your specifications:*
(Although you should be learning how to do it yourself, w3schools is a good place to start)

```
var products = ["phones", "computers", "whatever-other-product"]; //Create an array of your product names
var out="";
for(var i=0; i<products.length; i++){ //loop through the products array
    out+= '<div class="product"><a href="'+products [i]+'.html"><img src="images/'+product[i]+'.png" alt=" '+product[i]+' " /></a></div>';
}
elChild.innerHTML = out;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used product1, product2, and product3 as examples,  how can I replace them with phones.HTML , computers.HTML , cameras. HTML

Comment: Try using an array to store the values instead

Comment: @Stephen see my edited answer.. I do advise that you learn more about this through tutorial sites like w3schools

Comment: Please Samleo, I've tried to get some tutorials on how to append and display the products in div id='items' but i have failed, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) to insert child nodes to a parent.

```js
// You can also use a class name like this '.some-class-name'
const parentElement = document.querySelector("#some-id");

// Create the child element, it can be anything.
const childElement = document.createElement("p");
childElement.innerHTML = "some name";

parentElement.appenChild(childElement);
```

Now you can use the above example to create a piece of code that can insert multiple child elements.